# how fo feed a nullable parameter in a method?

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a method that can accept nullable parameters because it is filled from a table with nullable columns.

```
private void test(int ID, int? value)
{}
```

When calling this method I need some way to feed it a nullable variable and there is my problem.
I tried this :

```
foreach (DataRow row in DataTable1.Rows)
{
    test((int)row["ID"], (int?)row["value"]);
}
```

but it gives me a casting error

> "specified cast is not valid"

So I tried this :

```
foreach (DataRow row in DataTable1.Rows)
{
    test((int)row["ID"], (int)row["value"] ?? DBnull.Value);
}
```

and this :

```
foreach (DataRow row in DataTable1.Rows)
{
    test((int)row["ID"], (int)row["value"] ?? null);
}
```

but they both give me error

> "Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type int and null

Last one I tried is this :

```
foreach (DataRow row in DataTable1.Rows)
{
    test((int)row["ID"], (int?)row["value"] ?? null);
}
```

this one compiles but gives runtime error

> "specified cast is not valid"

So how can i do this ?
The idea is that the parameter value is filled with either a value from the table or with null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `DataRow` extension method [`Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) which supports nullable types:

```
foreach (DataRow row in DataTable1.Rows)
{
    int id = row.Field<int>("ID");
    int? value = row.Field<int?>("value");
    test(id, value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) (safe cast that returns `null` if it fails):

```
test((int)row["ID"], row["value"] as int?);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DataRow row in DataTable1.Rows)
{
   var id = row["ID"] as int? ??default(int);
   int? value = row["value"] as int? ??default(int?);

   test(id, value);
}
```